# Calculating words in each line (row) in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to calculate how many words there are per line in a `textarea`.

The width of the `textarea` might change.

This code snippet is calculating the number of rows: http://jsfiddle.net/2tcygj9e/

Comment: Take a look at the String "split" function.  If I understand your question, you should be able to split the textarea text by '\n' (line feed) and then split by ' ' (space).  This will initially leave the lines in an array, and then each line split by ' ' will leave each line as an array of words.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yashvadhvani/49xd6jo2/3/

Comment: I am sorry i didn't read your comment @JonTrent was trying that time on the fiddle and put the code

Answer (score 1):

You can try this I have already put in the comments its basically the combination of regex and split that you have to perform hope this helps...

```
const arr = textAreaValue.split(/\r*\n/);
arr.forEach((element, index) => {
    $('.tracker').append('<br />length of line' + (index + 1) + ':' + element.split(" ").length);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The other problem is line breaks. I am getting 300 words from database without line breaks. And in your jsfiddle example if i wrote 100 words, its couinting rows but it counting words in first line.